# Entity-framework error from dotNet CORE with existing business layer

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I have a dotNet 4.6.2 application that uses EntityFramework 6.0 and I just added a dotNet Core console app which target 4.6.2 as follows:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I need to access our existing business layer (and entityFramework layer) which expects a connectString in a config file.  I could not get the existing code to read the console app's appsetting.json (without modification), so I added an app.config and pasted in just the connectStrings from my existing web.config that works.

When I access the database I get the following error:

> The entity types 'APOrganization' and 'Organization' cannot
>   share table 'Organizations' because they are not in the same type
>   hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship
>   with matching primary keys between them.

Here is my app.settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyApp" connectionString="Server=(localdb)\msSqlLocalDB; Integrated Security=True; Database=MyDatabase; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I can't change the business later and existing entity framework code.

**Here is some more information:**
The APOrganization entity is bound to a table in the AP schema.  The class has this data annotation:

```
<Schema.Table("AP.Organization")>
```

The Organization entity is bound to the Organization table in the default (dbo) schema.

For some reason, EF *thinks* it is sharing the same table when it is kicked off from the Core app, but not when started by the 4.6.2 app.

Comment: Need to share more about your `APOrganization` and `Organization` types and why they both need to reference the "Organizations" table.

Comment: I will need to research this.  It's a large project and I don't know all the details.  My concern is why this works in the existing application but not when a dotNet core is kicking it off.  It happens on every database call, not just ones that use these tables.

Comment: Right. EF takes a Fail Early approach and always validates the structure of the model before it does anything else.
Regarding why it works in one project and not in another, there are actually some configurations and conventions that might be getting set (or removed) in the other project that change the way that EF behaves.

Comment: Just got your last edit. Could you verify that the tables are named "Organization" and not "Organizations"?

Comment: One table (in the database) is AP.Organization and the class that should point to it names it correctly with the schema.table annotation. The other table (db) is dbo.Organizations (with the S) and the class that points to it is name Organization (no s) and I think it pluralizes by default.  And this matches the error message (only pluralized is in the DB not the entity class).

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in EF 6.0.  It's fixed by 6.1.3.
https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1641

My dotNet core application had 6.0 installed, but the original application had 6.1.3 installed.  Interesting that the calling app version dedicates it and not the module where it resides.

I upgraded ans it's working.